# Write generic Makefile rule for subdirectories

Tags: makefile, fortran

I have a project with a directory tree that looks like this:

```
.
├── modules
│   ├── mod1
│   │   └── mod1.f90
│   ├── mod2
│   │   └── mod2.f90
│   └── mod.f90
└── src
    └── main.f90
├── bin
└── Makefile
```

`main.f90` uses all the modules found in `modules` and in the 'submodules' that are `mod1/` and `mod2/`.

A simple Makefile I can write to compile the project is something like:

```
F90      = gfortran
FLAGS    = -g -I$(BINDIR)
MODFLAGS = -J$(BINDIR)

BINDIR = bin
SRCDIR = src
MODDIR = modules
SMODDIR = $(dir $(wildcard $(MODDIR)/*/.))

MODFILES  = $(wildcard $(MODDIR)/*f90)
MODOBJ    = $(join $(addsuffix $(MODFROMBIN)/, $(dir $(MODFILES))), \
          $(notdir $(MODFILES:.f90=.o)))
SMODFILES = $(foreach smoddir, $(SMODDIR), $(wildcard $(smoddir)*f90))
SMODOBJ   = $(join $(addsuffix $(SMODFROMBIN)/, $(dir $(SMODFILES))), \
          $(notdir $(SMODFILES:.f90=.o)))
SRCFILES  = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*f90)
SRCOBJ    = $(join $(addsuffix $(SRCFROMBIN)/, $(dir $(SRCFILES))), \
          $(notdir $(SRCFILES:.f90=.o)))
ALLOBJ    = $(MODOBJ) $(SMODOBJ) $(SRCOBJ)
BINOBJ   = $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(sort $(notdir $(ALLOBJ))))

all: main

$(MODDIR)/../bin/%.o: $(MODDIR)/%.f90
        $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODFLAGS)
modules/mod1/../../bin/%.o: modules/mod1/%.f90
        $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODFLAGS)
modules/mod2/../../bin/%.o: modules/mod2/%.f90
        $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODFLAGS)
$(SRCDIR)/../bin/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.f90
        $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
main: $(ALLOBJ)
        $(F90) $(FLAGS) -o ./bin/main $(BINOBJ)

clean:
        @rm bin/*.o bin/*.mod
```

But now I want to write a generic rule to be able to compile all modules located in directories that are inside `modules` directory (the code I am working on have more than two submodules and I am not willing to write as many rules as I have subdirectories).

My first try was to write something like this:

```
$(SMODDIR)/../../%.o: $(SMODDIR)/%.f90                                                                                                                                                             
       $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ $(MODFLAGS)
```

but it fails; from what I understand, it will put all the subdirectories paths and I would actually end up with a rule that would looks like this:

```
modules/mod1/../../bin/ modules/mod2/../../bin/%.o: modules/mod1/ modules/mod2/%.f90
```

that indeed looks funny.

As shown in the original Makefile, it is possible to retrieve specificaly with

```
SMODDIR = $(dir $(wildcard $(MODDIR)/*/.))
SMODFILES = $(foreach smoddir, $(SMODDIR), $(wildcard $(smoddir)*f90))
```

so I guess it may be possible to use something similar to have more generic rules. I couldn't see however how to use such a syntax to write a rule that makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One could write rules to support this type of layout, but an an obvious question first is: why do you want to scatter source files all over your filesystem, rather than having them all together in `src`?

Comment: I did that a bit too quickly to have a MWE, sorry. I can however put `modules` in `src`, and my question is still valid (that is actually the layout of the original code).

Comment: Surely it'd still be a lot simpler to have `src/main.f90`, `src/mod.f90`, `src/mod1.f90` and `src/mod2.f90`? I'm not saying you can't/shouldn't have it the other way, but it's often easier to formulate an answer when we know why the more complicated situation exists.

Comment: Actually the real case would be more like `src/main.f90`, `src/modules/mod.f90`, `src/modules/mod1/mod1.f90`. The reason to scatter files in subdirectories is to gather bunch of source files  that are coherent. In the real code, that would for example correspond to different physical processes involved, and so on.

Comment: The problem isn't that you have source files in different directories.  That's fine.  The problem is that you want to put all your object files into ONE directory.  If your object files had the same directory structure as the source files, except under a different root like `bin`, then you could do it trivially with a single rule.  The problem you're having is that your source file and your object file can't be related to each other with a single pattern, if they have different directory structures.

Comment: So you'd suggest to keep the same directories layout inside `bin` to make it simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices to avoid writing lots of rules.

One is, you can use VPATH and put all your source directories in it, something like this:

```
VPATH := $(MODDIR) $(SMODDIR) $(SRCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/%.o: %.f90
        $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(MODFLAGS)
```

Or you can put all your object files into equivalent subdirectories of $(BINDIR), something like this:

```
MODOBJ    = $(MODFILES:%.f90=$(BINDIR)/%.o)
SMODOBJ   = $(SMODFILES:%.f90=$(BINDIR)/%.o)
SRCOBJ    = $(SRCFILES:%.f90=$(BINDIR)/%.o)

$(BINDIR)/%.o: %.f90
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(MODFLAGS)
```